# Hibernate/SQL Server - Cascade insert?

Tags: hibernate

I know that in Microsoft Entity Frameworrk ORM, let's say I have entity A, which has sub entities aA, aB, aC etc.

If I do the equivalent of `session.saveOrUpdate(SomeAEntityObject);`

it will automatically save aAs, aBs, aCs etc bound to the A entity.

Right now using Hibernate, it doesn't do it.
So, am I suppose to add evything one by one ?

Or am I missing something ?

(using Hibernat with annotations)

Comment: I've solved this by simply adding "@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE})" below the "@OneToMany" annotations. (with full package names here to avoir ambiguity concernes with javax.persistence stuff.

Comment: You should add that as an answer (and accpet it) so others can find this easier

Comment: Of course, but at this point the site doesn't allow me to answer my own questions befour a certain time, then it doesn't allow me to mark my own answer as the solution for some more time, which makes a total delay of appoximately one day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this by simply adding "@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_‌​UPDATE})" below the "@OneToMany" annotations. (with full package names here to avoir ambiguity concerns with javax.persistence stuff.